# Jquery - swapping two DIV's html content

Tags: jquery, html, each, swap

I'm having trouble getting this method of swapping to work, using an 'each' loop after a button is pressed.

The loop iterates, but text does not do as thought.

perhaps i'm using the wrong method of assigning html to these tagged divs?.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.direction-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('off');
    $("#CW").each(function(i, el) {
      if ($(el).html() == "&#8634;") {
        $(el).html("&#8635;");
      } else if ($(el).html() == "&#8635;") {
        $(el).html("&#8634;");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.direction-toggle {
  margin: auto;
  width: 30px;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-right-width: 15px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.direction-toggle.off {
  background: rgba(200, 230, 255, 1);
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-left-width: 15px;
}
#CW,
#CCW {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="twist-left">&#65513; R 1
  <div id="CCW" class="direct">&#8634;</div>
  <div class="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="twist-right">L 1
  <div id="CW" class="direct">&#8635;</div>&#65515;
  <div class="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="direction-toggle">
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wJftm/1/

Comment: There is only only one element with id of "CW". Why are you using an iterator?

Comment: I had multiple elements on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you properly, use this code:

```
$(function() {
  $('.direction-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('off');
    var twistLeftHtml  = $('.twist-left').html();
    var twistRightHtml = $('.twist-right').html();
    $('.twist-left').html(twistRightHtml);
    $('.twist-right').html(twistLeftHtml);
  });
});
```

Or this:

```
$('.direction-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('off');
    var twistLeftDirectHtml  = $('.twist-left .direct').html();
    var twistRightDirectHtml = $('.twist-right .direct').html();
    $('.twist-left .direct').html(twistRightDirectHtml);
    $('.twist-right .direct').html(twistLeftDirectHtml);
});
```

And remember that `id` attribute must be unique in DOM. Selection by id `$('#CW')` will return only first matched element.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wJftm/3/)

Comment: ah, I wanted to swap CW and CCW;

Comment: `$(function() {
      $('.direction-toggle').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('off');
        var cw  = $('#CW').html();
        var ccw = $('#CCW').html();
        $('#CW').html(ccw);
        $('#CCW').html(cw);
      });
    });
  `

adapted to this and it works fine. Thanks!